# 1980s or 90s magazine story: girl can read emotions because she sees outside the normal visual range

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This would have been in either Analog or IASFM in the mid-to-late 1980s or early-to-mid 1990s.

Loner boy meets outcast girl, who he discovers can read anybody's emotions.  They fall in love, they get separated, years later they meet again.  She's become a successful psychic, he's become a professional debunker.  He proves she's not psychic by discovering that she can see beyond the visual spectrum and thus read cues that are invisible to everyone else.

Comment: I don't recognize it, but it strikes me that the "loner boy" is drawing a *very fine* line when he says, in effect: "Sure, I admit she has the unique ability to accurately 'see' other people's emotions, thanks to her having been born with a strange ability to perceive things which the rest of us are incapable of ever learning how to see with our eyes, no matter how hard we try -- but that shouldn't be taken as proof that she is 'psychic'!"

Comment: What she was seeing wasn't visible to the (normal) human eye, but could be detected by (appropriately tuned/filtered) cameras.  If it's possible to reproduce the effect technically, it's not paranormal.

Comment: I gathered that was what you were saying, but I'm still thinking it's a fine line. I'm not sure that being able to reproduce a strange effect, by using scientific means, automatically proves the original event was not worthy of such labels as "psychic" or "paranormal." Once upon a time, being able to "see" what someone famous was doing right now, a thousand miles away from the observer, would have been called "clairvoyance," and thus "paranormal." Now I just have to turn on my TV. Does that mean clairvoyance is not paranormal?

Comment: Since humans are physically incapable of seeing appreciable radiation in spectra outside visible light (anyone who could see outside these spectra would have an organ that would look rather different from the eye), and since someone's infrared emissions, say, don't differ much between anger or lust or any other emotion that produces body heat, anyone who could determine someone's emotions by seeing their subvisual radiation would indeed have a supernatural ability, if not the one people thought.

Comment: It's like, Superman can't psychically determine the brand of people's underwear! He was just born with the ability to emit "X-rays" from his eyes. Anyone could do that with the appropriate machine, right? Nothing supernatural there.

Comment: @Adamant: And said ability is perfectly normal where he comes from. Magellan, a superhero webcomic, had a bit about that kind of situation, which some of the academy students joining to discuss how they sometimes feel out of place because they're just normal people who are considered abnormal on Earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be "[The Lesser Magic](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49336)" by Gregory Kusnick in *Analog*, April 1987. According to "[Fantasy Review](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Lesser+Magic%22+Gregory+Kusnick+%22fantasy+review%22&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG6sCUiZXjAhWS0KYKHcV9BY4Q_AUoBXoECAQQBQ&biw=534&bih=736)" it's about a scientific examination of a psychic's powers.

**They fall in love, they get separated, years later they meet again. She's become a successful psychic, he's become a professional debunker.**

> Houston pivoted and strode upstage to his chair. "On my left is Thalia Sky, the well-known San Francisco psychic. On my right is Dr. Marc Bannard, writer, lecturer, Stanford University psychologist, and president of the California Society of Rationalists. Dr. Bannard, perhaps you could start by telling us just what your group stands for."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Marc flinched away from that gaze, still shocked at seeing her again. He'd heard of Thalia Sky, of course; what debunker hadn't? Yet until today he'd never met her, nor seen a picture of her—nor dreamt in his most fevered nightmares that sweet, shy Thea Welkin could grow up into such a creature.

**He proves she's not psychic by discovering that she can see beyond the visual spectrum and thus read cues that are invisible to everyone else.**

It's Marc's department head, John Verrine, who figures that out.

> "*Aspergillus sudophilus*," Verrine replied. "A species of skin fungus related, if I recall correctly, to the yeasts. It's quite widespread, though basically harmless; I suppose that's why it hasn't drawn a lot of attention. I had to search through quite a few journals to find a description of it."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "It seems to be some kind of fluorescent effect," Verrine explained, "rather like a Day-Glo pigment. Lord knows what purpose it serves. Perhaps none, perhaps it's merely a side-effect of some routine biochemical activity. But apparently it's not at all uncommon for microbes of this general type to show some kind of fluorescence, at one wavelength or another. This one seems to absorb energy in the near ultraviolet, at about 3000 angstroms, and re-emit it rather broadly around 3500 angstroms—so close to the visible, in fact, that ordinary window glass is largely transparent to it. The exact spectrum—"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> He gestured toward the incubator. "The temperature in the box right now is thirty-five degrees Celsius: typical human skin temperature. If I change the temperature—" He reached out and adjusted a knob; on the monitor the microbial glow became marginally greener. "—the spectrum of luminescence changes. We've also found it to be remarkably sensitive to changes in acidity, moisture, applied electric field, and a number of other factors. A kind of natural polygraph, if you will. The journal articles I found make no mention of that aspect of it. But then who'd think to look, eh?"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Verrine turned to Marc, waved the folder in his face. "You see? Change just one DNA codon, one protein, one retinal pigment—and where we see blue, she sees ultraviolet. That portrait in your office was the key: all low-frequency colors, reds and greens and yellows. No blue in the picture at all, except for the facial aura—"
>
> "Marc," Thea cut in. "Marc, what is it? What's he saying?"
>
> "Just a minute!" Marc squeezed his eyes shut, pressed his hands to his temples. *Ultraviolet vision?* he thought wildly. *Fluorescent skin fungi? It's crazy . . .*

Comment: @user14111, I read snippets of it in Google Books and I thought it's not an unreasonable guess. I can't go into details since they were snippets and it would be tiresome and probably not coherent. Fantasy Review is now linked, it doesn't appear to have more details about the storyline. If you want to post it as answer with quotes and explanations, I'd be fine with that.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks for the quotes; they prove it's definitely the story I was thinking of.  (I remembered later the bit about the painting being a clue, but hadn't had a chance to add that to the question.)

Comment: He's not wrong that it's crazy. There are various kinds of *Aspergillus*, but *sudophilus* isn't one of them, so far as I can see. And even if such a fungus existed, and a human could see its UV fluorescence, the truth is that there would be so much fuzziness along every part of the pathway, particularly the precision of the human's eye to detect the temperature variations in the spectrum, that there's no way it could serve as good lie detector. Polygraphs, operating on those principles and mentioned in the story but with technological precision, are actually extremely unreliable.

Comment: One part is halfway true. There *are* certain mutations that could provide the ability to see into the ultraviolet, like corneal thickness mutations or maaaybe an extra cone cell. In fact, you can see into the ultraviolet yourself with eye surgery. Psychic powers not guaranteed.